# Returning incorrect values with complex numbers in Python

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I'm working a physics problem with complex numbers and think I'm setting everything up correctly but am obviously not doing something right along the way. It could be that I'm either not using the right equations or that I'm unfamiliar with how Python's handling the math, and I'm pretty sure I'm using the right stuff. I've already worked a problem using the same kind of procedure and got the correct value, so substituting my new values should

Given `f = 1000, SWR = -5.9, L = 0.081`, I apparently should be getting `z = 1.4 - 0.23j`.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
import numpy as np
import cmath

f = 1000     #frequency
SWR = -5.9
L = 0.081

w = 2*f*np.pi     #angular frequency
c = 343     #speed of sound in air
k = w/c     #wavenumber

BA = (SWR-1)/(SWR+1)     #given
theta = 2*k*L-np.pi     #given

z = (1+BA*np.e**(1j*theta))/(1-BA*np.e**(1j*theta))     #given
print(z)
```

This gives me `z = (-4.699946746470462-2.3316919882323677j)`, obviously not what I'm being told is the correct value.

I've gone over this multiple times now and can't find anything wrong. I just again worked through the problem I already got correct and made the minor substitutions to fit these given values, and I'm still getting the returned value of z. I don't want to tell my professor his "check that your code is giving the correct results" result is wrong, but...

Am I missing something?

E: Apologies for the rough display, but I'm not sure I can type in LaTeX here. The following are what I'm working with. Furthermore, the final image shows that I worked basically the same problem correctly and that I should be able to just make some substitutions to work this one. Also note that in my code, z is actually z divided by the rho*c*S quantity. I'm after that, don't need to know their values.

[Equation for z, BA, theta, and the worked similar problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAtTa.jpg)

Comment: It's impossible for us to know what you are doing wrong, as we do not know what you are actually trying to do!  If you could provide the mathematical formula(s) you are trying to implement, it would help considerably.

Comment: What if you do the calculations by hand?

Comment: @JohnColeman Working it out by hand and putting it through WolframAlpha gave me the same result Python is.

Comment: @Zafi I've updated the post with everything that should be needed.

Comment: Why do you believe the correct result is 1.4 - 0.23j?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov My professor put a comment on the assignment that as a check, the value for f = 1000 should be 1.4 - 0.23j. That's my only reason for thinking my work is wrong despite the evidence against that.

Comment: It is probably that some formulas are incorrect. Python code seem to be correct. Is it OK that you don't have x_min in your code (I see this in a document you reference in theta calculation)?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov Oops, yeah, I forgot to mention that I'm using L in my code in place of L-x_min. That part's not it. And the only changes I should be making between the worked-out problem and this one is when I'm getting theta. In the worked out problem, I was given lambda which allowed me to get k and thus theta (the frequencies cancel out), but for this I am given the frequency and know c, so as k = w/c I can proceed from there in the same way as previously.